# bash: iteration within for loop with numbers

Tags: bash, for-loop

The following bash script automatically produces N number of files using i number in the naming according to the given sequence:

```
prod_parts=30

for i in $(seq 2 $prod_parts); do
prev=$((i - 1))
next=$((i + 1))
printf "something" > ext0"$i".txt
done
```

which produces 29 filles with the names

```
ext029.txt  ext026.txt  ext022.txt  ext015.txt  ext011.txt  ext05.txt 
ext030.txt  ext023.txt  ext019.txt  ext016.txt  ext09.txt   ext06.txt
ext027.txt  ext024.txt  ext017.txt  ext012.txt  ext07.txt   ext02.txt
ext028.txt  ext020.txt  ext018.txt  ext013.txt  ext08.txt   ext03.txt
ext025.txt  ext021.txt  ext014.txt  ext010.txt  ext04.txt
```

how could I modify my script to automatically remove ZERO starting from the 10th, which should give me something like:

```
ext09.txt  ext26.txt  ext22.txt  ext15.txt  ext11.txt  ext05.txt 
ext30.txt  ext23.txt  ext19.txt  ext16.txt  ext09.txt   ext06.txt
ext27.txt  ext24.txt  ext17.txt  ext12.txt  ext07.txt   ext02.txt
ext28.txt  ext20.txt  ext18.txt  ext13.txt  ext08.txt   ext03.txt
ext25.txt  ext21.txt  ext14.txt  ext10.txt  ext04.txt
```

Comment: What are the `prev` and `next` variables used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probably could solve your problem would be using `printf` to format the numbers with the exact number of digits that you need:

```bash
prod_parts=30
for i in $(seq 2 "$prod_parts"); do
prev=$((i - 1))
next=$((i + 1))
## print the number $i using at least 2 digits
## padding with 0s if necessary into $suffix
printf -v suffix "%02d" "$i"
printf "something" > ext"$suffix".txt
done
```

Comment: with `bash v 3.1+` you can use the `printf -v` form to eliminate the subprocess call (`$(printf ...)`) on each pass through the loop; replace `suffix=$(printf "%02d" "$i")` with `printf -v suffix "%02d" "$i"`

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you, this is important. I updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell `seq` to do zero-padding using the [`-w` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html#index-_002dw-13). Compare:

```bash
$ seq 9 10
9
10
```

vs.

```bash
$ seq -w 9 10
09
10
```

So, for your case:

```bash
for i in $(seq -w 2 "$prod_parts"); do
    prev=$((i - 1))
    next=$((i + 1))
    printf "something" > ext"$i".txt
done
```